# Можно ли отнести слова "простереть" и "стрела" к этимологически однокоренным?

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "простереть" и "стрела" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря Черных я почерпнул следующие сведения:

1. *Стрела* от основы * *strēl-*, которая встречается только в балто-славянских и германских языках, с индоевропейским корнем * *ster-*. В качестве родственного упоминается *струна*.
2. *strēl-* означало ещё и *луч*, например древнерусское *стрѣла* и древневерхнемецкое *strāla* — *молния*. Современное немецкое *Strahl* — *луч* и *струя*, значение *стрела* устарело.
3. *Простереть* (у Черных упоминается *простор*, но не суть) тоже восходит к корню * *ster-*, но со значением «расширять, распространять»*.

Вроде морф один и тот же, однако семантика, на первый взгляд, прямо противоположная. Я порылся в справочниках Покорного, Коблера, Уоткинса и увидел, что там несколько корней * *ster-* с разными значениями.  В каких отношениях они состоят, мне пока не удалось разобраться. Впрочем, у Уоткинса оба вышеуказанных мною значения указываются для одного корня. Видимо, значение менялось так: «распространение» > «то, что движется, покрывая, заполняя собой; струя, луч» > «нечто тонкое, движущееся; стрела».
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
* Русское *строить* тоже восходит к этом корню.